# ssl page not securing not sure why https://www.englishandproud.org/donate/

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I have this web site for a customer and that their site is not resolving for https now i have set-up exactly same as other site does ssl require dedicated ip address could that be the reason this is not securing it says some elements are not securing

https://www.englishandproud.org/donate/

Answer (score 1):

you should include all external files using https.

The following are being fetched using a non secured url:

http://www.britainfirst.org/wp-content/uploads/it-file-cache/builder-core/script.js

http://www.britainfirst.org/wp-content/plugins/wp-slimstat/wp-slimstat-js.php?sw=1280&sh=1024&cd=24&aa=0&id=227df&ty=0&sid=170f91a4d79c0eb180ebde832415db7d&bid=0&pl=java|flash|mediaplayer|

http://www.britainfirst.org/wp-content/uploads/it-file-cache/builder-core/javascript-footer.js

Answer (score 1):

The following three files are being loaded over standard HTTP. They look to be part of one of the plugins you're using for your site.

http://www.britainfirst.org/wp-content/plugins/wp-slimstat/wp-slimstat-js.php?sw=1152&sh=864&cd=24&aa=0&id=227de&ty=0&sid=91f95638b19dadc52127c4d4d9f59ca0&bid=0&pl=java|acrobat|flash|mediaplayer|silverlight|

http://www.britainfirst.org/wp-content/uploads/it-file-cache/builder-core/javascript-footer.js

http://www.britainfirst.org/wp-content/uploads/it-file-cache/builder-core/script.js

Answer (score 0):

The following two elements on your page are accessed with `http://` and not `https://`:
`http://englishandproud.org/favicon.ico`

`http://englishandproud.org/wp-content/themes/BuilderChild-Default/images/favicon.ico`

Please update those links or remove the reference to the protocol altogether like:
`//englishandproud.org/wp-content/themes/BuilderChild-Default/images/favicon.ico` which will work for both secure and non-secure connections.